# Unable to save an vallues in database, instead 0 is saved

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm new to php and I'm trying to make a javascript array. But i dont know how to save it in database. When I tried to saved a value always 0 is saved in database.

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function tot(elem) {
var d=document.getElementById("total").value;

var h=(total+vat5+vat12_5)-cash_discount;
document.getElementById("grand_total").value = h;
}

var total = 0;
function getValues() {
var qty = 0;
var rate = 0;
var obj = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
      for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
     if(obj[i].name == "qty[]"){var qty = obj[i].value;}
     if(obj[i].name == "rate[]"){var rate = obj[i].value;}
     if(obj[i].name == "amt[]"){
if(qty > 0 && rate > 0)
{obj[i].value = qty*rate;total+=  (obj[i].value*1);}
     else{obj[i].value = 0;total+=(obj[i].value*1);}
            }
         }
    document.getElementById("total").value = total*1;
       total=0;
}

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addRow(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                   case "text":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                        break;
                case "checkbox":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                        break;
                case "select-one":
                        newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                        break;
            }
        }
    }

            function deleteRow(tableID)
{
        try
             {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
                for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++)
                    {
                    var row = table.rows[i];
                    var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
                    if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked)
                        {
                        if (rowCount <= 1)
                            {
                            alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                            break;
                            }
                        table.deleteRow(i);
                        rowCount--;
                        i--;
                        }
                    }
                } catch(e)
                    {
                    alert(e);
                    }
  getValues();
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<table border="1" id="dataTable" width="70%" align="center"
cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="normal-text">
 <tr>
 <td width="28"><input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" 
style="width:25px"/></td>
 <td width="80" align="center"><input type="text"  name="qty[]" 
 id="qty" onkeyup="getValues()" style="width:81px; border:hidden;
 text-align:center;" onBlur=""></td>
<td width="86" align="center"><select name="des[]" id="des" 
 onChange="getValues()">
<option value="0">SELECT</option>
<option value="FB">FB</option>
<option value="KM2">KM2</option>
<option value="KM4">KM4</option>
<option value="OR2">OR2</option>
<option value="OR4">OR4</option>
<option value="SB2">SB2</option>
<option value="SB4">SB4</option>
<option value="OB2">OB2</option>
<option value="OB4">OB4</option>
<option value="ORB2">ORB2</option>
<option value="ORB4">ORB4</option>
<option value="CB2">CB2</option>
<option value="CB4">CB4</option>
</select>
</td>
<td width="87" align="center">
<input type="text"  name="rate[]" id="rate" onKeyUp="getValues()" 
style="width:80px; border:hidden; text-align:center;" value=""></td>
<td width="90" align="right">
<input type="text"  name="amt[]" id="amt" style="width:80px;
border:hidden;text-align:right;""onKeyUp="getValues()" 
readonly="readonly">   </td>
</tr>
</table> 
Gross Total: <input type="text"  id="total" name="total[]"   
style="width:80px; text-align:right" value=""readonly="readonly">

<input type="button" value="Add Row" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" >
<input type="button" value="Delete Row" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')" >
```

PHP Query:

```
$qty    = $_POST['qty[]'];
$Des    = $_POST['des[]'];
$Price  = $_POST['rate[]'];
$Amnt   = $_POST['amt[]'];
$gross  = $_POST['total[]'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO special(special_id, qty, des, rate, amount, gross_total)                                                                                          
        VALUES( '$special_id','$qty','$des','$rate','$amount','$gross')";
mysql_query($sql1);
```

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or any live working snippet ?

Comment: which column is always saved as 0?

Comment: column qty, rate, amt, total and the des column is always blank

Comment: At least you making `$sql` but eval other  -` $sql1` - `mysql_query($sql1);`

Comment: @czacha remove the square brackets [] while takin _post value 
$Des    = $_POST['des'];

Comment: I tried to remove that bracket.  But nothing change. Its always 0 :( @splash58

Comment: @czacha these were mistakes that I saw. to debug, echo $sql, may be it will clear